# Create region bounded by parametric curves

Tags: regions

How can I define a region that is bounded by a set of parametric curves?

E.g. three parametric curves - which are cubic Bezier curves - define the boundary of a shape:

```
cubicbez[a_, b_, c_, d_, t_] := (1 - t)^3*a + 3*(1 - t)^2*t*b + 
  3*(1 - t)*t^2*c + t^3*d

bezierRegion[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := 
 ParametricRegion[cubicbez[a, b, c, d, t], {{t, 0, 1}}]

regions = {bezierRegion[{{5, 5}, {10, 13}, {18, 4}, {20, 30}}], 
   bezierRegion[{{20, 30}, {18, 40}, {17, 40}, {15, 35}}], 
   bezierRegion[{{15, 35}, {25, 25}, {5, 20}, {5, 5}}]};

Show[Region /@ regions, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Shape defined by a chain of parametric curves]

Is there a way to get the inside of that shape as a Mathematica region?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

- Another way is just use

```
Show[Region /@ regions, Frame -> False] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

- 

```
BezierCurve[{{5, 5}, {10, 13}, {18, 4}, {20, 30}, {18, 40}, {17, 
    40}, {15, 35}, {25, 25}, {5, 20}, {5, 
    5}}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics
```

- 

```
fig = Graphics@
   FilledCurve@
    BezierCurve[{{5, 5}, {10, 13}, {18, 4}, {20, 30}, {18, 40}, {17, 
       40}, {15, 35}, {25, 25}, {5, 20}, {5, 5}}];
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[fig]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach: You can use the coordinate data to define [`BezierFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html)s and use them to construct a polygon which can be used as is as a region or discretized using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`:

```
bzfuncs = {BezierFunction[{{5, 5}, {10, 13}, {18, 4}, {20, 30}}], 
   BezierFunction[{{20, 30}, {18, 40}, {17, 40}, {15, 35}}], 
   BezierFunction[{{15, 35}, {25, 25}, {5, 20}, {5, 5}}]};

poly = Polygon[Join @@ (Map[#]@Subdivide[100] & /@ bzfuncs)];

RegionQ @ poly
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[LightBlue], poly}]
```

[image]

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ poly
```

[image]